# Check user has permissions for a sharepoint site

Tags: 2010, development, permissions, object-model

On a SharePoint site I've created a permissions group with contribute permission level.

I've added an active directory group Domain/group1 to the SharePoint group.
The group has around 100 of domain users.

How do I programmatically get users from the group and how to I check if the users have the permissions to the site?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314767/getting-members-of-an-ad-domain-group-using-sharepoint-api

Answer (score 0):

Use [SPWeb.GetUserEffectivePermissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getusereffectivepermissions(v=office.14).aspx) this will return which permissions the user has.